# Pass options to vuejs components registered globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs2

I am registering my vuejs components in this way:

index.js (A separate reusable npm+webpack project: myComponents)

```
import MyButtons from './src/components/my-buttons.vue'
import MyInput from './src/components/my-inputs.vue'
export default {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.component("my-button", MyButtons);
        Vue.component("my-input", MyInput);
    }
};
```

Another project where I am using the above components with `npm link`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './vue/App.vue' 
import MyComponents from 'myComponents'

Vue.use(MyComponents, {
    theme: 'SomeTheme',
    color: 'SomeColor'
});

new Vue({el: '#app',   render: h => h(App)});
```

Now what I want to do is in `install()` function somehow pass the options to the components being registered and save them. So that I can control the color and theme in such a way that every instance of these components render according to the theme and color, where these components will have more then one theme/style and color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way of solving this problem is to put the settings on the Vue prototype.

e.g.:

```js
install(Vue, options) {
  Vue.prototype.$myLibraryOrPluginName = { options }
  Vue.component("my-button", MyButtons);
  Vue.component("my-input", MyInput);
}
```

Then inside the components you can access the options using:

```js
this.$myLibraryOrPluginName.options.theme
```

The way I've defined it here the `options` would not be reactive. You'd need to get `Vue.observable` involved to add reactivity:

```js
Vue.prototype.$myLibraryOrPluginName = Vue.observable({ options })
```